# Making a dictionary for value in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add dictionaries which have a key from each element from the list and value(s) from one following element from the list and a count for the number of times it follows it, in dictionary format. For example, if we have the list of words, `['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']` and if the key is "the", I want the values to be {‘dog’: 1, ‘cat’: 1}. The entire output should be `{‘the’: {‘dog’: 1, ‘cat’: 1}, ‘chased’: {‘the’: 1}, ‘cat’: {‘chased’: 1}}`.

My code so far can generate key and values but not in dictionary in dictionary format. Could someone help on this?

My code:

```
line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = {}
for i, item in enumerate(line):
    print(i, item, len(line))
    if i != len(line) - 1:
        output[item] = line[i+1]=i
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'The': 'cat', 'chased': 'the', 'the': 'dog', 'cat': 'chased'}
```

Comment: I don't understand how do you build the output.. Can you explain more please?

Comment: first, change `output[item] = line[i+1]=i` to `output[item] = line[i+1]`, otherwise you wouldn't get the output shown.

Here you need to check whether the item already exists as a key first. Then, in case it doesn't, create a dict with { line[i+1] : 1 }. If yes, just add 1 to the corresponding value. [...] wait, just saw that you want `{‘the’: {‘dog’: 1, ‘cat’: 1}...`. Then its a bit different. 1 Moment

Comment: shouldd't  `'dog':{"the"}` be in the dict too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this. Example -

```
line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog','the','dog']
from collections import Counter
output = {}
for i, item in enumerate(line):
    print(i, item, len(line))
    if i != len(line) - 1:
        output.setdefault(item.lower(),Counter()).update(Counter({line[i+1]:1}))

print(output)
```

`.setdefault()` first checks if the key exists, if it doesn't it sets it to the second argument and then returns the value at that key.

In Counter , when you do `.update()` , if the key already exists, it increases the count by 1 , so this seems like the correct structure to use for your case.

Also, Counter behave just like normal dictionary, so you can later on use them just as any dictionary.

---

Demo (Please do note the modified input to show a scenario where `'dog'` followed `'the'` twice) -

```
>>> line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog','the','dog']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> output = {}
>>> for i, item in enumerate(line):
...     print(i, item, len(line))
...     if i != len(line) - 1:
...         output.setdefault(item.lower(),Counter()).update(Counter({line[i+1]:1}))
...
0 The 7
1 cat 7
2 chased 7
3 the 7
4 dog 7
5 the 7
6 dog 7
>>> print(output)
{'dog': Counter({'the': 1}), 'cat': Counter({'chased': 1}), 'chased': Counter({'the': 1}), 'the': Counter({'dog': 2, 'cat': 1})}
```

Comment: `the` followed `dog` , I modified the input a little to show a little more complex scenario. Please do not compare the output with input from OP's question, compare with actual input from the demo.

Comment: I see, sorry that not noticing the difference of input.

Answer (score 4):

I did not test it but something like that maybe? Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for t, token in enumerate(line[:-1]):
    output[token.lower()][line[t + 1].lower()] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line that is causing the trouble for you is this line:

```
output[item] = line[i+1]=i
```

It looks like you aren't taking into account that output[item] should point to a dictionary. It looks like you needed to lowercase the words so they will compare correctly.

I was able to get the output you wanted with the following code:

```
line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = {}
length = len(line)  # I didn't wanted to check this each iteration
for i, item in enumerate(line):
    item = item.lower()
    if i != length - 1:
        next_word = line[i + 1].lower()
        if item in output:
            output[item][next_word] = 1
        else:
            output[item] = {next_word: 1}
print(output)
```